# Animation End Listener doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, css, animation, event-listener

I've got an animation with CSS for my time bar with `id="progress-bar"` and the animation class `.anim`.
The animation is CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  from {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #86e01e;
  }
  to {
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #f63a0f;
  }
}

.anim {
-webkit-animation: myfirst 5s linear;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

I'm restarting the animation with the function `reset()`

```
function reset() {
document.getElementById("progress-bar").className = "";
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("progress-bar").className = "anim";},1);
}
```

Now I want the function `lose()` to be executed, when the animation ends.
I've also tried multiple things with animationend listeners but it doesn't work for me...

```
var x = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
x.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
lose(); //whatever i type here doesn't work
}, false);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qahrp2b9/

Comment: @Kharchi I think you didn't understand what I'm trying to do. I want to execute a javascript function when the animation ends.

Comment: Ok, can you use jquery?

Answer (score -1):

Try this as a fix:

```
x.addEventListener('animationend', lose(), false);
x.addEventListener('webkitanimationend', lose(), false);
```